# Uninitialized pointer works as if it was initialized

Tags: c++, qt

This is some Qt code: (5.1.1)

```
QTreeWidgetItem *rootItem;

rootItem->setText(0, "Column 1");
rootItem->setText(1, "Column 2");
rootItem->setText(2, "Column 3");
rootItem->setText(3, "Column 4");

ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(rootItem);

Messages::ShowMessage(rootItem->childCount());
```

That above code works, one would expect a run time error because rootItem is uninitialized but yet it works. What am I missing here? I am using Qt Creator.

Have they done some sort of auto-initialization? If yes, where do I turn it off? I run the program and I get 4 columns. It makes no sense.

However when I try to actually initialize the pointer, I am only getting 1 column.

```
QTreeWidgetItem *rootItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);

rootItem->setText(0, "Column 1");
rootItem->setText(1, "Column 2");
rootItem->setText(2, "Column 3");
rootItem->setText(3, "Column 4");

ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(rootItem);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You mean, why doesn't undefined behaviour give the behaviour you expected? That's because it's undefined.

Comment: turn on warnings and you see the complaint

Answer (score 4):

It's *undefined behavior*, so you can't expect any logically reasonable or consistent behavior when you encounter them.

In practice however, you can improve the chances of the runtime system detecting those kind of error by setting your pointer to `nullptr` or `NULL`.

```
QTreeWidgetItem *rootItem = nullptr;
```

Also running your program in debug mode may also help, and many modern compilers can emit diagnostics and warnings when it detects those (you should always enable them, setting them to the highest, most paranoid level).

Note however that the above doesn't guarantee you anything, and it's still on you to make correct and well behaving code.

And again here comes the plethora of suggestions for you to use plain objects (the stack-allocated, non-pointer pointed ones), or if you can't (like, if your poor library is allergic to them<sup>[1]</sup>), always use pointer wrappers such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, or something that your library provides and is capable of digesting.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>I don't like those kinds of libraries.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If you add

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wall
```

or less strict:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wuninitialized
```

to your `.pro` file, compiler will complain and you will catch this issue - you will be forced to use something like:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *rootItem = NULL;
```

or

```
QTreeWidgetItem *rootItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't guarantee undefined behavior doesn't *appear* to work, and you were unlucky to run into that. The memory the uninitialized pointer points to is probably up for grabs so there's no run-time error, but you can't rely on this.

Most compilers will issue a warning (do you have them turned on?). Also, there are many that on debug builds initialize the pointer to some dummy value to signal an error - and you'd get an access violation crash on run-time.

Answer (score 1):

> One would expect a run time error. What am I missing here?

Using an invalid pointer gives undefined behaviour. That does not necessarily mean a runtime error; it means that anything could happen.

> Have they done some sort of auto-initialization?

Presumably, that's an automatic variable inside the class. If you don't specify an initialiser, they are not initialised at all (either to a valid or "known invalid" value); the initial value is indeterminate (whatever garbage happens to be in that lump of memory), and using the value gives undefined behaviour.

It's entirely possible that the pointer points to a lump of addressable memory, in which case the program might appear to work. That memory won't contain a properly initialised `QTreeWidgetItem`, and might well contain other objects which you are corrupting, so this could cause even more inscrutable errors later.

> If yes, where do I turn it off?

Enabling compiler warnings (`-Wall` or specifically `-Wuninitialized`, if you're using GCC) should catch most uses of uninitialised variables. Avoiding pointers and `new` except when you really need them will also help, although I don't know whether that's an option when dealing with Qt.

(I don't know enough about Qt to answer the final question, sorry).